# Prioritize Visible Content Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, pagespeed

I am running a Wordpress site and created a custom theme. 
Now I'm stuck with optimizing it for `Google PageSpeed`. It shows the following for the Mobile page:

> Consider Fixing: Only about 63% of the final above-the-fold content could be rendered with the full HTML response

This appears since I've included the `Featured Image` above my posts on the index.php with the code:

```
<p>
  <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>    
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </a>
  <?php endif; ?>
</p>
```

How can I fix the issue? It doesn't seems to me that I'm loading something like a sidebar before the featured image, apart from the logo of the site. For a deeper comprehension, here the complete code of my index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="content">
      <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <p>
          <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>    
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
              <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </a>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </p>
        <h1>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
          </a>
        </h1>
        <p>
          <?php the_content(__(' <br /> <br /> Weiterlesen →')); ?>
        </p>
        <hr> 

      <?php endwhile; else: ?>
        <p>
          <?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?>
        </p>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if (show_posts_nav()) : ?>
        <div class="pagination">
          <?php echo paginate_links(); ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
  </div>
  <div id="delimiter">
  </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Can someone help me with this issue? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

As someone who holds a 100/100 pagespeed score, I can tell you that over-optimizing for speed is probably not worth the frustrations you're going to run into fixing the problems. Case in point, run a Pagespeed test on Wikipedia or YouTube. These are top sites and YouTube only has a score of 50, for example. The real reason you'd want to improve these numbers is to provide a better experience to users because they don't have to wait for the page to load.

Your above the fold content is simply what is allowed to be displayed while waiting on additional resources to load:

> Your page has 4 blocking script resources and 2 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.
>   None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML.
>   **Remove render-blocking JavaScript:**
>   /…-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11.3
>   /…s/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1
>   /…ghtbox/jquery.touchwipe.min.js?ver=1.4.6
>   /…ightbox/jquery.lightbox.min.js?ver=1.4.6
>   **Optimize CSS Delivery of the following:**
>   /wp-content/themes/1000PB/style.css
>   /…ghtbox/styles/lightbox.min.css?ver=1.4.6

Your efforts are best spent optimizing the delivery of these, (using `async` or `defer` for scripts and stylesheets) since those will lower your overall pagespeed score and hurt your search engine rankings.

To answer your question, though, you can inspect elements that are towards the top of your page, generally anything that can be seen without scrolling down, to see their css. Example:

```
img.attachment-post-thumbnail {
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
    padding: 3px;
}
```

So that stuff is best included in an inline `<style>` element in the header, as then the browser won't have to wait for `style.css` to load before it can show the page to users.

If you need help with hacking your Wordpress theme to do certain things to make it faster, such as minifying scripts, making scripts asynchronous, using `defer`, disabling emoji, and so on, just ask in comments or submit another question and we will be glad to help.

[image: Screenshot of PageSpeed Score]

I recommend testing on other sites to get a better idea of what's going on. I recommend Webpagetest.org and using a Waterfall chart will tell you which resources are taking the longest:

[image: Webpagetest.org Waterfall Chart]

> You can also use tools to help with this:
>   **[CSS Tricks: Authoring Critical Above-the-Fold CSS](https://css-tricks.com/authoring-critical-fold-css/)**
>   **[Critical-path (Above-the-fold) CSS Tools](https://github.com/addyosmani/critical-path-css-tools)**

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply! This was really helpful! But I'm just a little bit confused - I've tried to do inline CSS for critical above the fold content, but it didn't removed the issue - when I am deleting the code for displaying the featured image above the single posts on the front page, the message "Prioritize visible content" disappears. But I do want to show the image. Is it maybe not a problem of CSS, but of the structure of my php code in the index.php (code see above)? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Prioritize visible content is only a mild warning, if you view your pagespeed you will see that "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content" has a big red exclaimation point meaning it's much more important. In other words, making your scripts load asynchronously will have more of a benefit. I must say though, your site loads very fast for me and I'm all the way in California USA. Your site is fine, it works good. I wouldn't remove functionality from your site due to speed concerns. Make an awesome site first and optimize it

Comment: Hi NextLocal, thanks for your post. Having my page at a score of 90% will cause glitchy / unfinished rendering on slower internet speeds. Silly is that the page seems to be more likely showing up at a rating of 60 than at my actual ~90. I guess the kitchen is messed up by critical section.
right now js is loaded async, that works as expected (I hope), but page fold still plays tricks with me :/ 
is there anything you can read out? https://www.webpagetest.org/result/170226_D5_1ZVB/1/details/#step1_request37
thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @MartinPfeffer your website looks very good and loads extremely fast for me. Unfortunately I can not provide CSS debugging for you, but your page is fast enough to get high rankings so if further optimizations are causing you problems it's best to leave it as it is, where everything is still easy to work on.